# Adjust the number of ticks on y axis, barplot() in R

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, graphic

I need make few things to get more ticks on y axis, as shown in the image below, but I am not managing to do that. Any help will be appreciated a lot!
This far I have typed:

```
Temp<-table(airquality$Temp)
barplot(Temp, col = "red", border = "blue",xpd = FALSE)
```

Comment: Maybe `barplot(Temp, col = "red", border = "blue", xpd = FALSE, yaxp=c(0, 12, 12))` which also adds labels.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want ticks and no labels, you can use `axis` with `seq` and `labels=FALSE`

```
Temp<-table(airquality$Temp)
barplot(Temp, col = "red", border = "blue",xpd = FALSE)
axis(2,at=seq(range(Temp)[1],range(Temp)[2],by=1),labels=FALSE)
```

[image]